# Can I build from source using just the PKGBUILD file, or do I have to checkout the whole source tree?

Tags: arch-linux, compiling, pkgbuild

I want to build Vim from source in Arch Linux to get various non-standard features in the resulting binary. I notice that the PKGBUILD file has URLs in it. Does this mean I can do the build with just this file?

```
$ asp export vim
(modify PKGBUILD as needed)
$ sudo makepkg
```

...or do I need to checkout the whole source tree?

Answer (score 0):

With `asp`, you have two options, both documented in the `man` page. The first is to just grab the build files: `export`:

> export TARGET...
>              Dump the build source files for each target into a directory of the target’s name in $PWD. Targets can be specified
>   simply as package to check
>              out the source files at HEAD, or in repository/package format to checkout the source files which were used to push the
>   package which exists in
>              repository.

And `checkout` also acquires the build files but initialises a git repository in the process.

> checkout TARGET...
>              Create a new git repository containing the full source and history for each of the given targets. The new repository will pull
>   from the
>              repository in $ASPROOT and must be updated separately after using asp update. If a checkout occurs on the same filesystem as
>   $ASPROOT, most of
>              the metadata can be hard linked, making this a relatively cheap copy.